# Get, for every instant, the rows with all past values to null in some column

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a MySQL table with an ID, a timestamp and another column. My application adds a row every 15 minutes for each ID with null or another value in the column. Eventually a new ID may appear or disappear.

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | time | column |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | 8:00 | A      |
+----+------+--------+
| 2  | 8:00 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 3  | 8:00 | B      |
+----+------+--------+
| 4  | 8:00 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | 8:15 | A      |
+----+------+--------+
| 2  | 8:15 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 3  | 8:15 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 4  | 8:15 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 5  | 8:15 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | 8:30 | A      |
+----+------+--------+
| 2  | 8:30 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 3  | 8:30 | B      |
+----+------+--------+
| 4  | 8:30 | C      |
+----+------+--------+
| 5  | 8:30 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | 8:45 | A      |
+----+------+--------+
| 2  | 8:45 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 3  | 8:45 | null   |
+----+------+--------+
| 4  | 8:45 | C      |
+----+------+--------+
| 5  | 8:45 | D      |
+----+------+--------+
```

I would like a query that gives me, for each timestamp, all the rows that have null in the column in the current and past rows.

Expected result:

```
+----+------+
| ID | time |
+----+------+
| 2  | 8:00 |
+----+------+
| 4  | 8:00 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 8:15 |
+----+------+
| 4  | 8:15 |
+----+------+
| 5  | 8:15 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 8:30 |
+----+------+
| 5  | 8:30 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 8:45 |
+----+------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below query should work for you. It is checking for each id if there is null in the 'col' in the current row and previous row.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.time
FROM
    test t1
WHERE
    t1.col IS NULL
    AND ((SELECT MAX(col) FROM test WHERE id = t1.id AND time < t1.time) IS NULL);
```

Comment: Great @skelwa!! It works!! And the query is quite simple and clear! I've been working on this for two days!! :)

Comment: You can change SELECT MAX(col) to SELECT SUM(col) if you want to check for all previous rows. MAX(col) is only checking for immediate previous one.